# ZedGraph Restrict Zoom and Pan to a specific area

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I want to restrict Zooming and Paning in a ZedGraph char to a certain area, e.g. inside X [-5;5] and Y in [-10;10] the user can zoom and pan however he likes, but he is never able to see outside that area.
Any advice? I tried settings ZedGraphControl.ScrollMaxX/Y & ZedGraphControl.ScrollMinX/Y but it didn't have any effect.